# date() function returning Invalid Date in Safari and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, date, datetime, safari

I am formatting a date in the following way:

```
date = new Date("2013-05-12 20:00:00");
formattedDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate());
```

When I run this in Chrome it outputs:

```
Sun May 12 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Which is what I need, however when I run this in Firefox or Safari I get

```
Invalid Date
```

Can any one suggest a workaround for this. Extra points if it doesn't require a library, regex or string manipulation.

Answer (score 16):

While the value `2013-05-12 20:00:00` is one several valid formats specified by [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), it is best to use the profile defined in [RFC3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt), which is a sub-set of ISO8601.

This means that you should have both the `T` separator, and a time zone offset - which can be numeric or `Z` to specify UTC.  In other words, you should use a value like `2013-05-12T20:00:00-07:00`, or the equivalent `2013-05-13T03:00:00Z`.

Now whether you have a correctly formatted input value or not, then the issue of browser compatibility comes up.  All modern browsers support ISO8601, but some interpret it differently.  For example, in Google Chrome, if you omit the `T` it is parsed as local time even if there is a `Z` at the end.  In Internet Explorer, the same value with the `T` omitted returns an invalid date error.

A better approach is to use a library that abstracts these differences away, so you can focus on your application and not the quirks of the browser.  The best library I know of for this is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).  In addition to full support for ISO dates, you can parse input in any way that you want with custom format strings.  It has lots of other features as well.  I highly encourage you to take a look.

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), you can do the following:

```
// from a full date-time-offset ISO8601/RFC3339 value
var m = moment('2013-05-12T20:00:00-07:00');

// or from your custom value, with explicit formatting
// this will assume the local time zone because you didn't specify one
var m = moment('2013-05-12 20:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

// then you can output it in a custom format if you like
m.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); // "Sunday, May 12th 2013, 8:00:00 pm"
```

As far as I know, [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) works in all browsers - including older ones like IE6.

Answer (score 9):

Your date format is not standard for some browsers. To parse custom date time formats you can split it to separate values and use another `Date` constructor that accepts `year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds` and is cross browser compliant. For your case it will be something like this:

```
var date = "2013-05-12 20:00:00",
    values = date.split(/[^0-9]/),
    year = parseInt(values[0], 10),
    month = parseInt(values[1], 10) - 1, // Month is zero based, so subtract 1
    day = parseInt(values[2], 10),
    hours = parseInt(values[3], 10),
    minutes = parseInt(values[4], 10),
    seconds = parseInt(values[5], 10),
    formattedDate;

formattedDate = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Working example here http://jsbin.com/ewozew/1/edit

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this exact same issue today, do not use dashes as a seperator. This works fine in Chrome but not in Safari/iOS, replacing dashes with slashes fixes this issue. The Date function will otherwise break in Safari.

### Incorrect date string with with -

The following code will return the following

```
new Date('03-25-2017');
```

**Chrome:**

```
Sat Mar 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

**Safari:**

```
Invalid Date
```

So, simply replace **-** with **/**.

### Correct date string with with /

The following code will return the following

```
new Date('03/25/2017');
```

**Chrome**:

```
Sat Mar 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

**Safari**:

```
Sat Mar 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not hijack `Date` with [fix-date](https://github.com/kenberkeley/fix-date) at the beginning of your code?

```
import 'fix-date' // that's ok!
```

Comment: Well, it worked for me. I suppose like another commenter suggested its just a matter of getting slashes instead of dashes, and ensuring the T separates the date and the time. I concur with the sole issue and comment on the repo, from 3 days ago no less (repo is 5 years stale), that some tests are in order.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a 'T' between the date and the time to get it working fully.

```
date = new Date("2013-05-12T20:00:00");
```

There are quite a few possible datetime formats allowed in the spec and I don't think all browsers offer all possibilities. For Firefox see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

To be really safe cross-browser you might want to try the RFC2822 / IETF date syntax (basically the same as Chrome spat back out at you)