# Angular custom filters - formatting date issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

This is my Select and options should be in yyyy/MM/dd but they aren't

```
<select ng-model="date" ng-options="row.Triage_x0020_start_x0020_date as row.Triage_x0020_start_x0020_date for row in rows | jsonDate:'yyyy/MM/dd'| unique:'Triage_x0020_start_x0020_date'">
```

-- choose Topic --

This is my list which is displaying correctly row.Triage_x0020_start_x0020_date

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="row in rows | filter:businessUnit | filter:topic | filter:date">
    <p>{{row.ID}}</p>
    <p>{{row.BusinessUnit}}</p>
    <p>{{row.Topic}}</p>
    <p>{{row.Triage_x0020_start_x0020_date | jsonDate:'yyyy/MM/dd'}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is my list which is filter which converting json string to Date object.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ui.utils']);

myApp.filter('jsonDate', function ($filter) {
    return function (input, format) {
        return $filter('date')(new Date(input), format);
    };
});


myApp.controller('RowsListCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.rows = myJSON;
});
```

Question is why filter doesn't work in select > options and displaying string 2014-04-02 18:00:00

Comment: You may want to look into a [momentjs filter](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/mjf65wtp/).

Comment: Still doesn't work.Also momentjs filter it's pretty the same as  jsonDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should convert date to timestamp in your filter

```
app.filter('jsonDate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
  return function(input, format) {
    return $filter('date')(new Date(input).getTime(), format);
  };
}]);
```

But the date format `2014-04-02 18:00:00` won't work in Safari and Firefox when using `new Date()`, you can reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616950/date-function-returning-invalid-date-in-safari-and-firefox)

Comment: Thanks for your help but that doesn't work either.It's still the same works fine in ul li but in options doesn't.